# mongoDB Dropping all pooled connections message in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

I see this message very often in my sharded cluster deployment v.4.0 :

```
 2022-07-01T10:12:21.327+0200 I CONNPOOL [TaskExecutorPool-0] Dropping all pooled connections to member:27017 due to NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Connection pool has been idle for longer than the host timeout
```

Is it something to worry about or just normal behaviour when application is idle?

Thanks

Comment: on what version of MongoDB are you on?

Comment: 4.0.23 community

Comment: we had the same issue a while ago but with replica sets and we updated the MongoDB version to fix the issue. but for us, it was a false positive log message as our replicas where still intact.

Comment: thanks for sharing , we dont have any complains , but it is abit annoying to see it in the logs so I was wondering if somebody know abit more ...